# outputFileStream Return Null

Tags: java, android

```
public void writeUser() {

    String userInfo;
    FileOutputStream FOS= null;

    UserConnector user = new UserConnector();  // this is other class receive data from user
    user.modifyUserFromSignUpToDB();           // this method make all data as one string
    userInfo = user.getUserInfo();             // get data from the class as string

    try {
        FOS = openFileOutput("usersInfo.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        FOS.write(userInfo.getBytes());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException er) {
        Log.e("malek", "cann't create file user");
    } catch (IOException er) {
        Log.e("malek", "cann't write to file user");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (FOS != null)  FOS.close();
        } catch (IOException er) {
            Log.e("malek", "cann't close file");
        }
    }
}
```

FOS always return as null, I try to use getApplicationContext(), this, classname.this and still have same problem

Comment: where is  the file located?

Comment: in Package called DataBase

Comment: add the code of `openFileOutput` method

Comment: Sorry I do not understand, how add the code of openFileOutput?

Comment: you clic the "edit" button and copy/paste it

Comment: I make that, and still have same problem

Comment: public FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        return openFileOutput(name, mode);
    }

Comment: I solved :) by adding Context when call method write user()-----> public void writeUser(Context context){.....}